# Create component from a string

Tags: typescript, angular

I have some components that I'd like to add to my page dynamically.

I have their name in a config file `config.json`, currently the typescript classname `MySuperComponent`. I can put anything I want in my config file is the class name is not suited.

I've tried some code with component resolver, but I can't pass a string to it.

This works:

```
this.resolver.resolveComponent(MySuperComponent)
```

This doesn't:

```
this.resolver.resolveComponent("MySuperComponent")
```

How can I instanciate (and inject) a component from a String ?

Comment: I guess this [github issue](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1295) link should help you. Thanks :)

Comment: @PankajParkar The `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated, I'd like not to use it.

Comment: I think that Pankaj wanted to show you the use of `System.import` ;-) This applies in your case...

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I'm not using systemjs.

Comment: @blue112 you could something similar with `require` ;-)

Comment: @blue112 what do you use as module manager?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier What if I don't?

Comment: @blue112 what do you exactly mean? you use es5 without modules?

Comment: I may be loading every single file I need into the browser using `script` tags. Don't over assume. This question is about typescript and angular, not about using another tool to "automagically" solve my problem.

Comment: How can it determine which class belongs to "MySuperComponent" name without determined modular system? (By the way, the answer is "it can't").

Comment: @estus MySuperComponent is a class name.

Comment: @blue112 could you please update you question with which module loader loader you are using to transpile your files, otherwise you are not going to get answer..

Comment: Classes aren't defined as globals. And even if they are (but they aren't!), there's no guarantee that they will save their names after minification (there is a guarantee that they won't). The question cannot get an answer that will satisfy you because your assumptions on language capabilities are wrong.

Comment: There's no way how "MySuperComponent" can be resolved to certain class by means of TS. And the only way "MySuperComponent" can be resolved to certain class by means of A2 is when the provider is defined as a string: `{ provide: "MySuperComponent", useClass: MySuperComponent }`.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a map and provide it by a service that translates from string to type

```
import {MySuperComponent} from './MySuperComponent';

@Injectable() 
class ComponentTypes {
  types = {
    MySuperComponent: MySuperComponent
  };
  toType(name:string) {
    return types[name];
  }
}
```

where you use it

```
@Component({
  ...
  providers: [ComponentTypes],
})
class SomeComponent {
  constructor(private componentTypes:ComponentTypes) {}

  addDynamicComponent() {
    ...
    this.resolver.resolveComponent(this.componentTypes.toType("MySuperComponent"))

  }
}
```

See also [Angular2, manually resolve a type by string/name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436681/angular2-manually-resolve-a-type-by-string-name/35460200#35460200)

Comment: Enumerating every single component that I could instanciate seems completely underproductive.

Comment: This is how strong types work. See the linked question for other answers.

Comment: I am (and should be) a lazy programmer. When I implement a new component, I do not expect to updated a "component bank" file just to resolve them.

Comment: I understand that you don't like that, that doesn't automatically invent better solutions. Angular uses types. Types can only uniquely identified with an import or a full path. There are other options (again see the linked question) but they also have their drawbacks.

Comment: I know this is an old post. But recently I ran into the same problem. If you have found a better solution, please share. The best I found so far is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949647/resolve-type-of-component-from-string-in-angular2?answertab=votes#tab-top.

Answer (score 1):

Following the Pankaj's comment, you could use `System.import`:

```
let componentPath = (...)
let componentName = 'MySuperComponent';
System.import(componentPath)
        .then(fileContents => {
            return fileContents[componentName]
        })
        .then(component => {
            this.resolver.resolveComponent(component);
        });
```

Comment: Don't assume I'm using systemjs. I'm not particulary using any framework or loading library. Currently I'm using webpack, but I don't want to be tied to a loading library.