# Resolve Type<> of component from string in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to get type of component (`Type<T>`) from `string` value? Smth like:

```
let typeStr: string = 'MyComponent';
let type: any = resolveType(typeStr); // actual type
```

Comment: why you need this ? may i know

Comment: I made a directive which creates components dynamically, based on provided type. At the moment I have to declare a variable in the parent component and assign it's value to desired type, then bind this value to my directive in html layout. I want to get rid of this and just pass a string to directive.

Comment: I'd say to have a service in a module that contains an array of registered cmoponents  - type and selector. Use this service to find a type by selector and render it dynamically in your view. You will not be able to get a type based on a string as shown in example above. You also use angular's internal list of registered components but creating your own service will give you flexibility.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to create a variable in the template then? Like `<button createComponent='let type = MyComponent'>Create</button>`?

Comment: What do you mean by `type`? Do you want to get a reference to the `MyComponent` class based on its name?

Comment: @NitzanTomer yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't do that without maintaining a "registry" for your classes.

```
interface Component { }

type ComponentClass = { new (): Component };

const REGISTRY = new Map<string, ComponentClass>();

function getTypeFor(name: string): ComponentClass {
    return REGISTRY.get(name);
}
```

As for how to add entries to this `REGISTRY`, you have a few options, here are two:

(1) Manually add it after every class definition:

```
class ComponentA implements Component { ... }
REGISTRY.set("ComponentA", ComponentA);
```

Or make a function for it:

```
function register(cls: ComponentClass): void {
    REGISTRY.set(cls.name, cls);
}

class ComponentA implements Component { ... }
register(ComponentA);
```

(2) Use a decorator:
Just use the above `register` function as a decorator:

```
@register
class ComponentA implements Component { ... }
```

Comment: Do you have a working example for this? I'm unable to understand how to separate the above first code segment into different files in an actual project.

Comment: @nmy I don't have anything that, but this code used to work. What problems do you have with this?

Comment: I got this work by exporting `ComponentClass` type and `getTypeFor`. I used the decorator approach for  `register` by exporting that too. Is that correct? Should `Component` be an interface, can't we use a class for that?

Comment: @nmy There's no correct or incorrect. If it works for you then it's fine. `Component` can be a class if you prefer to have a base class

Comment: When I implement this in my project I had to face another problem. My components have constructors and they use different input parameters. Then compiler says I cannot use the `register` decorator. Because the component is not compatible with `ComponentClass`. Do you have any ideas how this can be handled?

Comment: Do they all have the same constructor signature(s)?

Comment: @nmy Try passing the interface type as the parameter to the register function. Like this:
`function register(ci: Component): void`
And then do something like this inside register function:
`let cls = ci as ComponentClass;`
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Just in case anyone stumbles across this question like me. It is possible without maintaining a registry.

Full credit goes to [yurzui for his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115072/how-to-load-component-dynamically-using-component-name-in-angular2).

Just a copy from there:

```
import { Type } from '@angular/core';

@Input() comp: string;
...
const factories = Array.from(this.resolver['_factories'].keys());
const factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === this.comp);
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
const compRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
```

Comment: FYI this no longer works in Angular 9 as they removed the `_factories` from CFR. That said it was probably best to stay away from private props anyways!