# Angular - Access to Component/Class from it's name

Tags: angular

I found a solution suggestion in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42949647/resolve-type-of-component-from-string-in-angular2) and tried to implement it to my project by adding below code in a global (ts) file.

```
interface Component { }

type ComponentClass = { new (): Component };

const REGISTRY = new Map<string, ComponentClass>();

function getTypeFor(name: string): ComponentClass {
    return REGISTRY.get(name);
}

function register(cls: ComponentClass): void {
    REGISTRY.set(cls.name, cls);
}
```

and then registered my every component like below:

```
class ComponentA implements Component { ... }
register(ComponentA);
```

I am getting my component type with **getTypeFor** method. Everything was nearly perfect when i try to put a parameter in constructor of a component. As i see, this "ComponentClass" type waiting a no parameter constructor. 
How can i use this method or any other solution if my cnonstructor have parameter(s).

Comment: Will all constructors share the same parameters? If so, change the definition of `ComponentClass` to match - otherwise afaik you're out of luck with this approach.

Comment: please share error text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below:

```
type ComponentClass = { new (...args:any[]): Component };
```