# Typecast string to component

Tags: angular

I have to create routing file in Angular Project,
and all path and component name are stored in database.

component will select as per login user rights

now I want to crate route array in routing module file.

I will get all rout path from data base according to user and make route array.

But I have no idea how to convert string component name to component.

Please help if anyone have idea.

Comment: Provide some code

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to return each component type based on the string value, something like this:

```
convertComponent(componentName: string) {
    switch(componentName) {
        case 'SomeComponent':
            return SomeComponent
            break
        case 'SomethingelseComponent':
            return SomethingelseComponent
            break
        // etc
    }
}
```

Then call it when you are making your routing module:

```
{ path: 'something/', component: convertComponent(componentNameString) },
```

You can also use a **registry map** instead of the switch case, and set the elements in each component you define.

Comment: You are right but still I have define all component in switch case. I have array which contains path and component name and on the bases of that I want to crate route array for app.routing.ts file. so I will give permission to selected user for only selected components. and on that route file user get their working menues

Comment: What's the problem of defining all components in the switch case?

Comment: that is already I did. But I have more than 100 components and it will be increase more. each time I have to put in switch case and make production and put on server. I will insert path and component name in table and when project run it will make it's route array in app.routing.ts.

so when ever I want to delete or insert component in table in database as per user login it will show.

So I think typecast will usefull to me but I have no idea how to use.

Comment: I don't see any problem to edit the switch case, while you are writing so much code for the component itself. As I think, the solutions to this problem are switch case OR using registry maps. Anyway, you can take a look at this answer if you don't wanna use those 2 methods and wanna go in a dirty way, and ready to handle unknown exceptions in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178914/1185148