# How to transform a String into a Type / Component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, components

In Angular, i get a String and want to transform it to a Type / Component. For example, i get "ListComponent" and want to add a ListComponent to the Application.
I dont want to map these in an Map or something. Is it possible to get the Type out of a String?

```js
stringComponent = "ListComponent";
typeComponent = *transform "ListComponent" to ListComponent;
method(typeComponent);
```

Comment: Does the component exist in your template?

Comment: `I dont want to map these in an Map` well you are stuck then aren't you. This question has been asked many times here and the answer is the same. There is no **string** representation for a component factory in the Angular API anywhere. Component factories have a string selector, but there is no way to get an array of all factories because they are bound to modules. Modules are a hierarchy but there is no way to get child modules from the application reference. So you're stuck.

Comment: @vsarunov yes, it exists.

Comment: @cgTag okay, yes i searched for it, but could not find any solution.. thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38636553/create-component-from-a-string

Comment: thanks to your answer, I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40115072/how-to-load-component-dynamically-using-component-name-in-angular2 which helped me a lot! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
class ListComponent {
  foo = 'bar'
}
class LolComponent {}

const componentsMap = {
  ListComponent,
  LolComponent
}

type ComponentName = keyof typeof componentsMap;


function convertStringToComponent<Name extends ComponentName>(name: Name): (typeof componentsMap)[Name] {
  return componentsMap[name];
}

const CompByName = convertStringToComponent('ListComponent');

const instance = new CompByName();

instance.foo; // ok!
```